# What are the forehead sides which lack hair called in English?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

Some people, when they grow up and become adults, tend to lose their hair on the sides of the forehead. What are these places called in English?

I've checked in my language dictionaries and I didn't find a translation for this word. In translation from my language these places are called "**[bays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bay)**", but it seems that this term is not valid in English for the condition that I described above.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure of a name for the "bays" of the head, but the hairline itself is referred to as a **[widow's peak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widow%27s_peak)**. This idiomatic term has fairly old origins:

> The term stems from the belief that hair growing to a point on the forehead – suggestive of the peak of a widow's hood – is an omen of early widowhood.

More general terms you can use are phrases like *receding hairline* to denote the hairline moving up one's head as they stop growing hair. As for terms for the "bays", something like **bald patches** or **bald spots** might be close to what you're looking for.

Comment: They would, I suppose, have to be _widow's valleys._

Comment: I'll agree with *receding hairline* and *bald spots* – those are the two I was thinking of, though I figure bald spots typically refers to more of a spot on the top of your head – but I think *widow's peak* refers more to the hairline naturally coming to a V in the middle of the forehead and not so much that it happens to turn into a V after the hair on either side stops growing.

Comment: I agree with cjl750: "receding hairline" is a better description than "widow's peak". As the name implies, women relatively often have hair that grows to a widow's peak, while it is much less common for women to exhibit male-pattern baldness.

Comment: @sumelic You'll have to take it up the with our friends at Oxford, then: they define _widow's peak_ as **["A V-shaped growth of hair toward the center of the forehead, especially one left by a receding hairline in a man.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/widow's_peak).**

Comment: @Catalouping (You might consider citing or linking to the Wikipedia entry you quote here...)

Comment: Well, I think that I found what I wanted to find. It is "receding hairline" which apparently the most used and spoken according Google. I'm pretty sure that the most of the native English speakers don't know what does it mean widows' peak. See here for example: https://www.thetrendspotter.net/2016/06/hairstyles-haircuts-for-men-with-a-receding-hairline.html

Comment: @VersatileandAffordable You're wrong about that. _Receding hairline_ means _any_ form of frontal hair loss. We certainly do know that _widow's peak_ refers specifically to the V-shape hairline in the graphic.

Comment: @ P.E. Dant, interesting find in Oxford there for widow's peak. I still say they're wrong :)

Comment: Also, it just occurred to me that we must have evolved the expression quite a bit if a **widow's** peak applies *especially* to men. It's not a widower's peak!

Comment: @cjl750 The issue is further complicated by Google's returning of the Oxford Dictionaries's definition at the top of a search for the term. The real OED (NOTE: _not_ "Oxford Dictionaries") presents a Longfellow quote: _" She had on her forehead what is sometimes denominated a ‘widow's peak’,—that is to say, her hair grew down to a point in the middle."_ The association with male hair loss seems to be recent. Myself, I hew to the older definition, especially since it seems originally to have been conceived as a feminine trait.